# When the confidence interval of an odds ratio includes one, can the p-value be less than 0.05?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, odds-ratio

When the confidence interval of an odds ratio includes one, can the p-value be less than 0.05?

For example,

```
odds ratio = 0.54  confidence interval ( 0.29 - 1.01 ) and 
p value is 0.039.
```

In this situation can we consider the effect to be statistically significant or not? 
Or is something wrong?

Comment: just checking, is the confidence interval a 95% confidence interval or some other percent confidence interval?

Comment: In addition to @JeromyAnglim's question, were the CI & the p-value calculated the same way? Eg, is one marginal (unadjusted) & the other conditional (unadjusted)?

Comment: This is discussed in [the vignette of the exactci R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactci/vignettes/exactci.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

If the confidence interval and the test are not quite based on the same calculation (in at least the somewhat loose sense that they give the same partial order to the sample space), then in some cases the two won't exactly correspond.

There are a number of cases where the usual interval and test are based on different statistics that give similar but not quite identical results.

If you give some more details of where (in what program) you saw this output and what data and commands you got it with, we might be able to give more details.

Comment: +1. I have seen this phenomenon in peer-reviewed publications and consider it an error to use two different procedures that produce contradictory results (unless that is noted and explained). Although some would argue that these differences are minor, the crux of the matter is that they can lead to radically different actions: in the case of the p-value, to publication (where the editors insist on a 5% threshold, as is the norrm); and in the case of the CI, to no publication.

Comment: @whuber I'd agree that they should be made to agree, or at the least noted and explained with care (in many common cases making the two agree isn't especially difficult). On the other hand I'd regard the policy of the journal as the much larger problem there. It would almost be worth tolerating the inconsistency in order that the silliness (and worse than silliness) of such a policy be made more obvious.